# Content Delivery Wizard: No files returned

Tags: content

I have created a CRM Content library, with some files as content. I have added the "Content Deliveries" related list to the Contact page layout. I click Deliver Content, it lands you in the Content Delivery Wizard, and I expected to be able to select one or more files from the library. No such luck. I tried several things, but always: No files returned.

Then I created a Content Pack in the library, and tried again, but that didn't help either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And a, maybe related, mysterious quote from the help documentation: "If Salesforce CRM Content functionality is enabled on the Opportunity tab, for example, Salesforce CRM Content uses the fields on the opportunity detail page to search for files that may be relevant to that opportunity. You can drill down in the search results as needed or run your own search and then attach one or more files to the opportunity." How do I enable Salesforce CRM Content functionality on the Opportunity tab?

Comment: I uploaded a file to Chatter and ended up in the Files tab. Turns out that this new file is also, automatically, added to My Private Files / Private Library. This file is found by the Content Delivery Wizard, but the others still not. Also: Salesforce tries to make you think that Files and CRM Content are different functionalities, but it seems they are connected.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the 'Library Administrator' permission does't have the 'Content Delivery' permission. I had the same problem and this solved it. See this article: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=content_delivery_create.htm

Permission to create content deliveries from a shared library in Salesforce CRM Content:
Member of the library
AND
**“Deliver Content” checked in your library permission definition**